# How to put a Label/unique ID on Date-time in Database or when analyzing data with R/Python?

Tags: python, sql, r

I am looking for a general solution in the database.It could be oracle or SQL server or the operation could be done in R/Python when I will import the data to R/Python. I have a Date-time(D-M-YY) column I want to put a label on it according to month. Day part is static it is trimmed by first day of the month. the month and year part is variable. For example:

```
Date    Label
1-1-16   1
1-2-16   2
1-3-16   3
1-4-16   4
.
.
.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes. I can split the date and make a code like 1-1-16 to 1116, 1-2-16 to 1216 then I can use RANK() function in SQL to make a label. But can not think how to do it in R or python. I am adding some  more info in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Finally my friend help me to find a solution in R, which is very simple,

date_sample <-c('1-1-2016','1-2-2016','1-3-2016','1-4-2016')

format(as.Date(date_sample,format = '%d-%m-%Y'),"%m")

It gives me output:
"01" "02" "03" "04"